# Confused about command: sed '/^#/d' ~/.profile

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, putty

I need to know what this command does.

```
sed '/^#/d' ~/.profile
```

The output that this command gives me is this:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

I know that this command:

```
sed '/^$/d' file.txt
```

means to delete blank lines in `file.txt`.

I know that `#` can mean the end of a command or a comment.

I know `$` indicates start of command.

What exactly the command

```
sed '/^#/d' ~/.profile
```

does?

Comment: Deletes all the lines starting with # = delete all comment lines = return pure code lines. In sed/regex `^` means "start of line" and `$` means end of line. `#` has no special meaning = treated literatelly

Answer (score 6):

The `sed` command line

```
sed '/^#/d' ~/.profile
```

will remove all shell comments that starts at the beginning of a line from the file `~/.profile`, e.g. the first, but not the second, of the following two lines:

```
# comment
  # indented comment
```

It does this by trying to match `#` at the start of the line (`^`) and will delete (`d`) any lines that matches.

To also strip indented comments from a shell script, use

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d' file
```

`[[:blank:]]` will match space characters and horizontal tabs.

---

`$` only means "start of a command" in the sense that it's the common prompt used by the shell to prompt you to type something on the command line.

`#` is the character that introduces a comment in the shell.  It serves no purpose in a `sed` script other than for matching a `#` in the input<sup>1</sup>.  I have never seen it used to signify the "end of a command".

---

<sup>1</sup> The `#` character introduces a comment in `sed` scripts too, if used between commands.

Answer (score 3):

`/^#/` matches lines that start (`^`) with a `#`. `d` deletes them. The default action of `sed` is to print the line (unless `-n` is given), so anything else is printed.

> I know that `#` can mean the end of a command or a comment.
>
> I know `$` indicates start of command.

Mm, no. In regular expressions, `^` marks the beginning of the string (or line), `$` the end. `#` is used as a comment character, so usually at the start of a line.

Note that many files using `#` as a comment character allow it to be used after a command, or otherwise not directly at the start of a line. It could be indented, as in the comment remaining in your example output.

Something like `/^ *#/d` (or `/^[ \t]*#/d`) might be better in that it would also remove indented comments.